# Firebase API Key not included in the reset password %LINK%

Tags: firebase-authentication

I'm working on the reset password functionality for my firebase auth app and I came across an issue that I can't seem to find a solution for.

The email is sent, however the %LINK% does not include the api key and this causes the following error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBZtj.png)

The Link that firebase generates is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgjdv.png)

I have checked the credentials screen from google console and I do have a browser key that was generated by firebase. I am also passing down the api key in the firebase config.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ko3ut.png)

Any suggestions?

1. Check google console credentials for the api key
2. Included the api key in firebase config object
3. That's it - I can't edit the firebase reset password link manually.

Comment: I'm getting exactly the same... did you find a solution?

Comment: Me too! :( I'm using FlutterFlow - same issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you delete the provider, and then re-add it, it should work!

1. Firebase
2. Authentication
3. Sign-in method
4. Click Edit (pencil) icon for Email/Password provider
5. Delete provider
6. Re-add it